# Hide current container depending on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following html that when a user selects leasehold additional form fields appear:

```
<label for="hold_type">Leasehold / Freehold: </label>
<select id="hold_type" name="hold_type">
  <option value="null">--</option>
  <option value="lease">Leasehold</option>
  <option value="free">Freehold</option>
</select>
<span class="required">*</span>

<div class="section_hidden">
    <label for="lease_remaining">Years remaining on lease: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lease_remaining" name="lease_remaining" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['enquiryData']['lease_remaining'])); ?>" />
    <span class="required">*</span>
</div>
```

The jQuery I am attempting to use and adapt is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".section_hidden").css("display", "none");
    $("select#hold_type").change(function() {
        if ($('select#hold_type option:selected').val() == "lease") {
            $('.section_hidden').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.section_hidden').css("display", "block");
            $.cookie('holdSection', 'expanded');
        } else {
            $(".section_hidden").fadeOut("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $(".section_hidden").css("display", "none");
            $.cookie('holdSection', 'collapsed');
        }
    });
});
```

There are more that one `section_hidden` divs on the page, hence the user selection should only show the `div.section_hidden` container that is below it rather the entire page. I have tried a combination of `closest()`, `find()` and `next()` but haven't managed to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a wrapper element:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="hold_type">Leasehold / Freehold: </label>
    <select id="hold_type" name="hold_type">
      <option value="null">--</option>
      <option value="lease">Leasehold</option>
      <option value="free">Freehold</option>
    </select>
    <span class="required">*</span>

    <div class="section_hidden">
        <label for="lease_remaining">Years remaining on lease: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lease_remaining" name="lease_remaining" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['enquiryData']['lease_remaining'])); ?>" />
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".section_hidden").hide(0);

    $("select#hold_type").change(function() {
        var $section_hidden = $(".section_hidden", $(this).closest(".wrapper"));
        if ($('select#hold_type option:selected').val() == "lease") {
            $section_hidden.fadeIn("fast");
            $.cookie('holdSection', 'expanded');
        } else {
            $section_hidden.fadeOut("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $.cookie('holdSection', 'collapsed');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use id

```
<div id="section_hidden1">

$("#section_hidden1").css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next('.section_hidden')` doesn't work?

Comment: No, because `$(this).next()` would return the `.required` span.  Since that span is not `.section_hidden`, `$(this).next('.section_hidden')` returns an empty jQuery object.

Comment: Well, then $(this).next().next() would work, given that your structure is always the same.  It would of course be better to wrap the related elements together, or give the hidden section an id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#hold_type` and `.section_hidden` share a common parent, and there is only one `.section_hidden` in the common parent, this should get you the correct element:

```
$(this).closest(".commonParent").find(".section_hidden");
```